# Watir Webdriver : How can I disable loading ads using watir

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

I am trying to automate a website, but what is happening is that the ads are taking very long to load thus the complete suite is taking a long time to complete.

Is there a way I can disable loading ads using watir webdriver ? I don't want to disable it on the browser as I have to test ad slots on the website as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't really watir-related, but you could set the ad-host URL to 127.0.0.0 in your hosts file.  This would cause those ads to resolve instantly the host and the ads to never load.

Windows:

- windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts

OSX:

- /private/etc/hosts

  ads.advertiserswebhost.com 127.0.0.0